# How to push object into an array using serializeArray in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select html element which is serialized. I need to serialize the value, data-price attribute and also the option text. The script is working but i'm pushing one object too much to the array.

jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/kh3k7ame/3/

[image]

```
<form id="order">
<select name="selectProduct" id="selectProduct">
            <option selected disabled hidden style="display:none;" value=""></option>
            <option data-price="1.50" value="16">Product1</option>
            <option data-price="0.50" value="17">Product2</option>
            <option data-price="0.50" value="18">Product3</option>
            <option data-price="0.30" value="19">Product4</option>
            <option data-price="0.30" value="20">Product5</option>
</select>
<button type="button" name="send" id="send">Send</button>
</form>

<pre id="result"></pre>
```

js:

```
var orderTotal = [];

$('#send').on('click', function(){
    var orderData = $('form').serializeArray();
    var orderValue = {};
    $(orderData).each(function(i, field){
      orderValue[field.name] = {value:field.value, text:$("#selectProduct option:selected").text(), price:$("#selectProduct option:selected").attr('data-price')};
    });
  orderTotal.push(orderValue);
  console.log(orderTotal);
  $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(orderTotal,null,4));
});
```

Comment: `orderTotal = orderValue;` maybe?

Comment: Please show what expected results are

Comment: I think the result is fine - you do not need a better code.

Answer (score 0):

if the select is a single select, I think you can save the value in an object rather than array.

https://jsfiddle.net/kh3k7ame/4/

```
$('#send').on('click', function(){
    var orderData = $('form').serializeArray();
    var orderValue = {};
    $(orderData).each(function(i, field){
      orderValue[field.name] = {value:field.value, text:$("#selectProduct option:selected").text(), price:$("#selectProduct option:selected").attr('data-price')};    
    });
  $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(orderValue,null,4));
});
```